# How to query for many composite primary keys in mysql?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, primary-key

Let's say I have a table with a column A, column B, and column C that make up a composite primary key. Now let's say I have like 10,000 values for those primary keys.

ex. (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9) ... etc for (A, B, C)

I want each row referenced by each primary key. What's the best way to do this?

I know naively I can just construct a select statement as such
`select * from table where (A = 1 and B = 2 and C = 3) OR (A = 4 and B = 5 and C = 6) OR (A = 7 and B = 8 and C = 9)...etc`

This seems kind of sketchy though and would result in kind of an insane SQL statement. Also i'm not sure how the performance would be on this? Even though its querying on primary key which are all indexed?

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this? Can i use `in` in any way?

Comment: For 10000 tuples it might be a good idea to create a table, insert them there and join the table.

Comment: "each row referenced by each primary key" is not clear. [ask] [Help] PS [mre] PS Ask exactly 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question.

Comment: Note:  This Question and its answers also apply to non-Primary indexes.  Or even to an un-Indexed triple of columns.

Comment: You're asking more of a hypothetical question, rather than about a specific problem with a line of code, which makes your question lean toward being off-topic. SO is more about dealing with specific problems with code, not potential problems. If you can supply code, show how it goes wrong, and ask a specific problem about it then your question will have a better chance of being on-topic and answered.

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL, you may use tuple syntax:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (A, B, C) IN ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9));
```

In terms of efficiency, if you compare the explain plan of the above against your current more verbose version, I expect it would be roughly the same.  But my answer is a bit easier to read.

Comment: Those are also called "row constructors".  Caution:  Older versions of MySQL did not optimize such.